# how to replace a certain value of a column in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, database

how to replace a certain value of a column. for example I have three rows of values ​​in a table:

```
id_tweet: 1
status_user: RT @username1: success rta: P

id_tweet: 2
status_user: RT @username2: happy rta: D

id_tweet: 3
status_user: amen
```

of the three records above I want to replace or remove retweet text in the status_user column to:

```
after replace:

id_tweet: 1
status_user: success rta: P

id_tweet: 2
status_user: happy rtx: D

id_tweet: 3
status_user: amen
```

but I have constraints. I think I can use the replace function query on mysql as follows:

```
UPDATE tes_tbl_status
SET status_user = (SELECT REPLACE (status_user, '?', '') FROM 
tes_tbl_status WHERE status_user LIKE 'RT%:%')
WHERE status_user LIKE 'RT%:%';
```

> information : '?' = RT @...:

query above by replacing a certain value in the status_user column with an empty string value, however I do not yet know how to retrieve the text value

> RT @ ...:

which will be replaced with an empty string. anyone have any idea or solution for my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove always the `RT @...:` parts, the `SUBSTRING_INDEX`, `CONCAT` and `REPLACE` mysql functions are there for your help. Using `SUBSTRING_INDEX` you can extract the `RT @...` substring that you can CONCAT with a colon (`:`) and apply this result in the `REPLACE` function as the `from_str` parameter to be replaced by an empty string.

Here is the code what do the update for you:

```
UPDATE t
SET status_user = TRIM(REPLACE(status_user, CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(status_user, ':', 1),':'), ''))
WHERE status_user LIKE 'RT%';
```

***Result***:

```
+----------+----------------+
| id_tweet | status_user    |
+----------+----------------+
|        1 | success rta: P |
|        2 | happy rta: D   |
|        3 | amen           |
+----------+----------------+
```

Note the `TRIM` that i used to remove the leading and trailing spaces (if exist).

See ***[sqlfiddle demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2c03b7/1)***.

**DDL**:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
  id_tweet INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  status_user TEXT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO t (id_tweet, status_user) VALUES
(1, 'RT @username1: success rta: P'),
(2, 'RT @username2: happy rta: D'),
(3, 'amen');
```

Also there is a nice mysql udf library ([lib_mysqludf_preg](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg)) that can equips your mysql with PCRE pattern matching functionalities.

Comment: thanks. can you give me a reference related to your query.

Comment: Do you mean ***[SUBSTRING_INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)*** and the other [mysql sring functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html)?